# JS Keep Character's Regular Value

Tags: javascript, html, file, filereader

When I run my snippet (shown below), it replace the dashes (-), the single quote, and the double quote with �.

```js
var button = document.querySelector('#fileInput + button');
var input = document.getElementById('fileInput');
var text = null;
input.addEventListener("change", addDoc);
button.addEventListener("click", handleText);

function addDoc(event) {
  var file = this.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    text = reader.result;
    button.removeAttribute("disabled");
  };

  reader.onerror = function(err) {
    console.log(err, err.loaded, err.loaded === 0, file);
    button.removeAttribute("diabled");
  };
  a = reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
  console.log(a);
}

function handleText() {
  addtoPreviousOutput();
  changeOutputParagraph(text);
  button.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
}

function changeOutputParagraph(newText) {
  var element = document.getElementById("output");
  element.innerHTML = newText;
}

function addtoPreviousOutput() {
  var previousOutput = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML;
  var previousOutput_sOutput = document.getElementById("previousOutput").innerHTML + "<br />";
  console.log(previousOutput);
  console.log(previousOutput_sOutput);
  document.getElementById("previousOutput").innerHTML = previousOutput_sOutput + previousOutput;
}
```

```html
<p id="previousOutput"></p>
<p id="output"></p>
<input type="text" id="textInput" onkeypress="getText(event)" />
<input type="file" id="fileInput" accept="text/*" />
<button type="button" id="addDoc">Add Document</button>
```

Why is that and how do I fix it?

### Edit

[I get this when I run my file which is 176 lines and 22 KB.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fQFA.png) **Note:** This isn't all of the text.

Comment: Where does it replace dash, single and double quote?

Comment: It replaces it in the text, but only in larger files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`readAsText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText) reads the text as utf-8 by default. The reason you see � instead of your expected characters is because your text file is not utf-8 encoded.
You can pass the encoding of your file to readAsText to properly read the text.

e.g. for latin 1

```
a = reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0], 'ISO-8859-1');
```

Answer (score 1):

A FileReader can only read one file at the time, however you're trying to read the file twice:

```
reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
console.log(reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]));
```

There's no actual reason for you to do that. Just store the first read result - and print the data that you've already read.

Comment: thanks for helping me remove the error, but I wanted how do I remove the �